# how to find difference in single dimensional array with single dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array two array. First is multidimensional and other is single dimensional. I want to find difference between them. How do I found.

**$arrayresult**

**Array 1**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => ishani.lad [1] => 9033187384 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => rajkumar.prajapati [1] => 8460078459 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => lokesh.bhandari [1] => 9687060900 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => shishanshu.rai [1] => 8401915337 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => vishal.dake [1] => 9879815299 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => mohsin [1] => 8347163123 )
)
```

**$useduser**

**Array 2**

```
Array (
    [0] => ishani.lad 
    [1] => rajkumar.prajapati
    [2] => lokesh.bhandari     
)
```

I need difference as result as below
**Result**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => shishanshu.rai [1] => 8401915337 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => vishal.dake [1] => 9879815299 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => mohsin [1] => 8347163123 )
)
```

I have used solution as

```
$resultremainig = [];
foreach($arrayresult as $val2){                            
    if(!in_array($val2[0], $useduser)){                                                  
        echo $val2[0]."<br>";
        $resultremainig[] = $val2;
    }                            
}
```

But it show last record also. Result of above code is as below. It always show me last record in second array's also

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => lokesh.bhandari [1] => 9687060900 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => shishanshu.rai [1] => 8401915337 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => vishal.dake [1] => 9879815299 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => mohsin [1] => 8347163123 )
)
```

Comment: trim the value before checking `if(!in_array(trim($val2[0]), $useduser)){`

Comment: @jitendrapurohit I have solved my problem by trim.

Comment: great, added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you wanted you could try using nested loops like so:

```
<?php

    $arrOne = $arrFinal = [
        ["ishani.lad",         9033187384],
        ["rajkumar.prajapati", 8460078459],
        ["lokesh.bhandari"   , 9687060900],
        ["shishanshu.rai"    , 8401915337],
        ["vishal.dake"       , 9879815299],
        ["mohsin"            , 8347163123],
    ];

    $arrTwo = [
        "ishani.lad",
        "rajkumar.prajapati",
        "lokesh.bhandari",
    ];

    foreach($arrOne as $key=>$item){
        foreach($arrTwo as $k=>$v){
            if(in_array($v, $item)){
                unset($arrFinal[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($arrFinal);

    // PRODUCES:::
    array (size=3)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'shishanshu.rai' (length=14)
          1 => int 8401915337
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'vishal.dake' (length=11)
          1 => int 9879815299
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'mohsin' (length=6)
          1 => int 8347163123
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$output = array_filter($arrayresult, function($a) use ($useduser) {
  return !in_array($a[0], $useduser);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can also try this

```
    $one = array(array('ishani.lad',9033187384),array('rajkumar.prajapati',8460078459),array('lokesh.bhandari',9687060900),array('shishanshu.rai',8401915337),array('vishal.dake',9879815299),array('mohsin',8347163123));
            $two = array('ishani.lad','rajkumar.prajapati','lokesh.bhandari');
            foreach($one as $array){
                    if(!in_array($array[0],$two)){              
                    $final[] = $array;
                }           
            }
 echo "<pre>";print_r($final);
```

Output

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => shishanshu.rai
            [1] => 8401915337
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => vishal.dake
            [1] => 9879815299
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mohsin
            [1] => 8347163123
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the value before checking in `$useduser` array

```
$resultremainig = [];
foreach($arrayresult as $val2){  
  // this removes any extra spaces from the search string                          
  if(!in_array(trim($val2[0]), $useduser)){                                               
  echo $val2[0]."<br>";
  $resultremainig[] = $val2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [array_diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function.

Store your 2 arrays in variables and compare them.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of the function on the PHP manual page I linked you ;)